# Naming children after opposite gender

Tags: halacha, names, children-parenting, mesorah-tradition

Are there any issues with naming a boy after a woman, or a girl after a man? 
We do see many examples of people making male names more feminine e.g. Daniella, Gavriella.

I once heard that the latter may be more problematic as women are obligated in less mitzvot. Is there any truth to this? Are there any mainstream sources?